# Swift: Sort NSArray of CGPoints by one value, then another?

Tags: swift, nsarray, cgpoint

I'm trying to sort an NSArray of CGPoints (describing a CGPath) by their y values (descending), then by their x values (ascending). This is what I have so far (Swift code):

```
var anglePoints:[CGPoint] = [CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), CGPoint(x: 32, y: 32), CGPoint(x: 32, y: 0)]

anglePoints.sort { $0.0.y > $0.1.y }

// anglePoints is now equal to [CGPoint(x: 32, y: 32), CGPoint(x: 32, y: 0), CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)]
```

Obviously, sorting on x after this will result in the y values no longer being in order.

Is there a way to perform both sorts in a single call? Something like Linc's `OrderBy().ThenBy()`?

Comment: `anglePoints.sort { if $0.0.y != $0.1.y { return $0.0.y > $0.1.y } return $0.0.x < $0.1.x }`

Comment: Hmm, that's just acting the same as sorting the array twice (anglePoints is now equal to `[CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), CGPoint(x: 32, y: 32), CGPoint(x: 32, y: 0)]`...

Comment: @MassivePneguin no, it's not. If it is, then you did something wrong when copying the code.

Comment: Looks like your code was changed between when you originally posted it and when I answered...

Comment: I deleted my original comment because I misread the requirements. I was referring to my new comment – sorry if that was confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a single sort:

```
anglePoints.sort { $0.0.y != $0.1.y ? $0.0.y > $0.1.y : $0.0.x < $0.1.x }
```

which can be more explicitly written as:

```
anglePoints.sort {
    if $0.0.y != $0.1.y {
        return $0.0.y > $0.1.y
    } else {
        return $0.0.x < $0.1.x
    }
}
```

Translated in words: if the `y` coordinates are different, sort by `y`, otherwise by `x`

Comment: the second criterion should be `$0.0.x < $01.x` since x values should be sorted in ascending order.